# Floating JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox, floating

How to make floating JavaFX editable ComboBox? ComboBox options list is floating, but not the textfield. How can I make the textfield floating as well.

```
comboBox.setEditable(true);
comboBox.getEditor(). ...?
```

Image 1: [In this image, TitledPane "Funcionalidad is not expanded"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBhM2.png)

Image 2: [In this image, when TitledPane "Funcionalidad is expanded, the TextField "Código" is displaced down because of the ComboBox Textfield, but not because of the ComboBox options list. ComboBox options list is over the TextField "Código"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wviuI.png)

How can I make that the ComboBox TextField also be over the TextField "Código"?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. What do you mean by floating? How did you get the list to be floating? Providing drawings/illustrations or screenshots of similar UI may help clarifying your meaning.

Comment: Probably "floating" means inside the popup here....

Comment: i added 2 images for clarifying my question. Thanks!